# sum output from mysql - not right value

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I would like to sum 2 values, like 3,07 + 5.1 and I am getting result 8,10 €, not 8,17 €. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
$rezultat = "SELECT sum(value) as value FROM values";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $res) or die (mysqli_error($link));
$sum= mysqli_fetch_object($result);
echo number_format($sum->value, 2, ",", "");
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems a decimal separator issue. try replace "," by "." like this:

```
echo number_format($sum->value, 2, ".", "");
```

number_format(number,decimals,decimalpoint,separator)

see: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_number_format.asp

Comment: anyone else here to help?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$kategorija = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['kategorija']);

$vrednost = number_format(str_replace("#", ".", preg_replace("/[^0-9#]/i", "", preg_replace("/[\.\,](?!.*[\.\,])/i", "#", $_POST['kolicina']))), 2, ".", "");

$vrednost = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $vrednost);
```